# How to do pagination in select box based on scroll

Tags: html, angularjs, html-select, dropdown

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control choice requiredField" id-available name="SelectData" ng-model="box.box_id" title="Select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>{{'_SELECT_BEACON_' | i18n}}</option>
    <option value="{{y.box_id}}" ng-repeat="y in dataList" class="nms">{{y.beacon_code}}</option>
</select>
```

**ANGULARJS**

```
boxService.listUnassignedDevice(function(res) {
    $scope.dataList = res;
}, function(error) {
});
```

Here I have large data in "dataList"(10000>). So I need to list data in select box after mouse scroll down. First I have to show 100 data, when mouse scroll down, I need to show next 100 data from API.

Comment: Sounds like a _really_ terrible UI ... With that many values, you should perhaps rather not use a select field in the first place, but some autocomplete solution.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [ngInfiniteScroll](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BinaryMuse/ngInfiniteScroll/1.0.0/build/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js) directive and add script tag then add module `'infinite-scroll'`and then Use the directive by specifying an infinite-scroll attribute on an element.

```
<div infinite-scroll="myPagingFunction()" infinite-scroll-distance="3"></div>
```

> ngInfiniteScroll will call myPagingFunction() any time the bottom of
>   the element approaches the bottom of the browser window. See the API
>   documentation for more information about what attributes are available
>   for use, and take a look at the demos to see ngInfiniteScroll in
>   action.